# High/Low range under GBM - Analytic solution?

Tags: volatility, geometric-brownian, atr

Does anybody know of an analytical solution to the expected high / low range for an asset that follows a GBM process over sampling frequency dt? I have ran numerical simulations and find that the scaling rule is approximately: $$ 1.8\sigma * T^{0.522}$$

That's robust (r^2 = 0.98) against vols up to 50%.

I am trying to generate rules to provide real-time measures of the ATR using higher frequency price data, obviously real life differs from the GBM result but I am still curious if this problem has an analytic solution?

Thanks.

Comment: For the numerical simulations what drift rate do you assume, zero?

Comment: 0 drift, yes. .